# How to export an object/icon as svg from InDesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, vector, svg, export

I have a little basket icon as an object in InDesign file and I just want to save it as .svg file.

I have InDesign 2017 CC

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, InDesign doesn't have this functionality. If you have acces to Illustrator, you can copy and paste the object in Illustrator and save it as an `.svg` there.

Be warned that the object will be pasted into Illustrator with a clipping mask, which might create some problems or just plain won't work in .svg. Release the mask and expand / ungroup objects in Illustrator as necessary.